# Angular 8 NgClass parser error at the start of directive

Tags: angular, typescript

Im trying to dynamically set classes with ngClass in angular using the following html

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4" *ngFor="let caso of tareas">
      <div  [ngClass]="{
         'card card-outline-info shadow-box':caso.prioridad=== 'baja',
         'card card-outline-warning shadow-box':caso.prioridad=== 'importante',
          'card card-outline-success shadow-box':caso.prioridad=== 'completado',
          'card card-outline-danger shadow-box':caso.prioridad=== 'urgente',
          }"> 
 </div>
</div>
```

TS :

```
tareas:Tarea[] =[
      {
         prioridad:"baja",
         tipo:"Proyecto",
         nombre :"Migración",
         descripcion :"descripcion 1",

      },
      {
         prioridad:"urgente",
         tipo:"Caso",
         nombre :"Falla en acceso a DB2",
         descripcion :"descripcion 2",
      },
      {
         prioridad:"importante",
         tipo:"Proyecto",
         nombre :"Implementar WebSphere",
         descripcion :"descripcion 3",
      },
      {
         prioridad:"completado",
         tipo:"Caso",
         nombre :"caso alv",
         descripcion :"descripcion 5",
      },]
```

The error i get when compiling is the following
[image: Browser Output]

I have followed the tutorials exactly as they are written however i cant find why does the template have the error described above

Answer (score 1):

Angular template parser doesn't support trailing commas in templates:

```
'card card-outline-danger shadow-box':caso.prioridad=== 'urgente',
}"                                                              ^^^^
                                                         remove this
```

Comment: Still getting the same error after removing all the commas in the template

Comment: Then please copypaste it from this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ngwt2l?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html I'm pretty sure you're doing something wrong

Comment: Your solution makes the console output the same parser error but instead it says a bracket is missing

Comment: it displays the list but not the styles

Comment: Is it what you asked in your question?

Comment: Please check updated demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ngwt2l?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html Is it what you wanted?

Comment: No it really didnt change the output

Comment: Did I solve the issue with parser? Can we close this question and create a new one where you will describe what you want to achieve?